# Include tableView.contentInset on load

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uikit

How can I load a ViewController with the `contentInset` included on load?

```
[self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(300, 0, 0, 0)];
```

Right now this includes an inset, but it's above the edge of the screen and I need to scroll up to see it.

Comment: screenshot please

Comment: Set content offset as well if you don't want to scroll manually